# "unbound variable" reading a boolean parameter from shell script command line

Tags: bash, shell, parameter-passing

My apology for not being able to find such a seemingly trivial thing myself.

I need to pass more than one boolean parameter to shell script (Bash) as follows:

```
./script --parameter1 --parameter2
```

and so on.

All are to be considered `true` if set.

**In the beginning of the script, I use `set -u`.**

Normal parameter with value passing I currently do as follows:

```
# this script accepts the following arguments:
# 1. mode
# 2. window

while [[ $# > 1 ]]
do

    cmdline_argument="$1"

    case $cmdline_argument in

        -m|--mode)

            mode="$2"
            shift

        ;;

        -w|--window)

            window="$2"
            shift

        ;;

    esac

    shift

done
```

---

I would like to add something like

```
    -r|--repeat)

        repeat=true

        shift

    ;;
```

I do not understand why it does not work as expected.

It exits immediately with error:

> ```
> ./empire: line 450: repeat: unbound variable
> ```

Where the line 450 is:

> ```
> if [ "$repeat" == true ];
> ```

Comment: Can you clarify how it fails? Is it because you're missing a `shift`?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I tried it with and without `shift`.

Comment: You're using `set -u`, aren't you?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes.

Comment: It's the cause of your problem.

Comment: (and since you aren't including it in your question, that makes the question quite incomplete).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ok I will put it in there

Comment: See [BashFAQ #112](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112). And on a related note, **definitely** read [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) before using `set -e`.

Comment: As another aside -- `==` isn't a POSIX-specified string comparison operator; that would be `=`. The `==` extension is guaranteed to work in bash, but not baseline POSIX sh. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: As another aside -- `[[ $# > 1 ]]` is probably not code you actually want to use. `>` is a string comparison, not a numeric comparison, so `[[ 10 > 2 ]]` is actually false; either `(( 10 > 2 ))` or `[[ 10 -gt 2 ]]`, by contrast, will do a numeric comparison and thus be true.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you very much for sharing so much knowledge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `set -u`, it's an error to dereference any variable that hasn't had a value explicitly assigned.

Thus, you need to set `repeat=0` (or `repeat=false`) at the top of your script, or to use a dereference method that has an explicit default behavior when the value is unset; see [BashFAQ #112](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112).